# Chef newline not getting interpolated

Tags: chef-infra

I am writing a chef recipe. I have an attribute containing a string with newline in it. When I use the attribute to a File resource with content set to the attribute, the file generated contain the newline characters. I was expecting the file to contain multiline content.

example:

```
default['ssh_private_key'] = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nline1\nline2\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"


File '/tmp/private_ssh_key' do
  action :create
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0640'
  sensitive true
  content node['ssh_private_key']
end
```

I was expecting /tmp/private_ssh_key to contain:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
line1
line2
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Instead /tmp/private_ssh_key contains:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nline1\nline2\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I interpolate newline characters with actual line break?

My Chef client version is 13.6.4

Comment: `\n` is a convention that has to be supported by whatever compiler or whatever interpreting the text. If that syntax isn't supported, the `\` and the `n` will be inserted as separate characters.

Comment: Are you 100% certain you used double quotes in the recipe and not single quotes? You need the double for this to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. The issue was caused by an incorrect assumption that test-kitchen would automagically expand Ruby character escape sequences.

I created an environment variable:
`SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nline1\nline2\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"`

and in my .kitchen.yml file I had the following:

```
attributes:
  ssh_private_key: <%= ENV['SSH_PRIVATE_KEY'] %>
```

This overrides the attribute in my cookbook. But the YAML specification provides that "[escape sequences are only interpreted in double-quoted scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092)". I had to change the environment variable to the following to make interpolation work:

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="\"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nline1\nline2\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\""
```

Thanks again

Comment: Use `<%= ENV['SSH_PRIVATE_KEY'].to_json %>` instead.

Comment: hmmm...I get undefined method `to_json'.

Comment: You also need a `<% require 'json' %>` :)